# Beamer overprint environment altering vertical spacing of items

Tags: beamer, lists, line-spacing, overlays

I have a frame with an `itemize` environment where each `\item` contains an equation. Some of the equations will change, however, so I wrapped them in an `overprint` environment, so that one equation appears and is then replaced by another. This works just fine, but the vertical spacing of the items is not ideal, as can be seen below.
[image]
Compare the space between the `\phi_a` equation and the next item and that of the `\phi_f` equation and the next item. How can this be corrected? Or does it need to be done manually with `\vspace` or something of the sort?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item A NBR 6118 define $\phi$ como composto por três parcelas:
\begin{equation*}
\phi = \phi_a + \phi_f + \phi_d
\end{equation*}
\item $\phi_a$ representa a deformação rápida;
\begin{equation*}
\phi_a = 0,8\left(1-\beta_1\left(t_0\right)\right)
\end{equation*}
\item $\phi_f$ representa a deformação lenta irreversível;
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>
\begin{equation*}
\phi_f = \phi_{f\infty}\left(\beta_f\left(t\right)-\beta_f\left(t_0\right)\right)
\end{equation*}
\onslide<2>
\begin{equation*}
\phi_f = \phi_{f\infty}\left(\beta_f\left(t_i\right)-\beta_f\left(t_{i-1}\right)\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{overprint}
\item $\phi_d$ representa a deformação lenta reversível.
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>
\begin{equation*}
\phi_d = 0,4\frac{t-t_0+20}{t-t_0+70}
\end{equation*}
\onslide<2>
\begin{equation*}
\phi_d = 0,4\left(\frac{t_i-t_0+20}{t_i-t_0+70}-\frac{t_{i-1}-t_0+20}{t_{i-1}-t_0+70}\right)
\end{equation*}
\end{overprint}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`overprint` only copes well with fairly simple cases. I suspect that the use here does not count as sufficiently simple, at least without some sort of adjustments.

Simpler to use `overlayarea` for the entire `itemize` environment:

```
\documentclass[utf8]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{overlayarea}{\linewidth}{.75\textheight}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item A NBR 6118 define $\phi$ como composto por três parcelas:
        \begin{equation*}
          \phi = \phi_a + \phi_f + \phi_d
        \end{equation*}
        \item $\phi_a$ representa a deformação rápida;
        \begin{equation*}
          \phi_a = 0,8\left(1-\beta_1\left(t_0\right)\right)
        \end{equation*}
        \item $\phi_f$ representa a deformação lenta irreversível;
          \only<1>{%
          \begin{equation*}
            \phi_f = \phi_{f\infty}\left(\beta_f\left(t\right)-\beta_f\left(t_0\right)\right)
          \end{equation*}}
        \only<2>{%
          \begin{equation*}
            \phi_f = \phi_{f\infty}\left(\beta_f\left(t_i\right)-\beta_f\left(t_{i-1}\right)\right)
          \end{equation*}}
        \item $\phi_d$ representa a deformação lenta reversível.
        \only<1>{%
          \begin{equation*}
            \phi_d = 0,4\frac{t-t_0+20}{t-t_0+70}
          \end{equation*}}
        \only<2>{%
          \begin{equation*}
            \phi_d = 0,4\left(\frac{t_i-t_0+20}{t_i-t_0+70}-\frac{t_{i-1}-t_0+20}{t_{i-1}-t_0+70}\right)
          \end{equation*}}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{overlayarea}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: slides with <code>overlayarea</code> for <code>itemize</code> environment]